# addOnCompleteListener method in Facebook authentication with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I´ve done everything in the Firebase walktrough to Authenticate with a Facebook account. Even though I still can't connect them. I can login using Facebook (in the app) but it never stores as a new user in Firebase. 
Please help me if you can detect my error.

When I try to Authenticate in Firebase with Facebook (via Android app) it doesn't enter to `addOnCompleteListener` method inside the handleFacebookAccessToken method. 
The last thing showed by the Logcat is this message:

```
-app: Entered handleFacebookAccessToken, credential:com.google.firebase.auth.FacebookAuthCredential*******
```

I'll share my code in my Login Activity.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.qeri.qeri.MainActivity.MainActivity;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

CallbackManager callbackManager;
private TextView textView;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

private static final String TAG = "-app";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_screen);
    Log.d(TAG, "Layout created in LoginActivity");


    //FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Auth_Key);

    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile"));
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess " + loginResult);
                handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
            textView.setText("Login Canceled");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
            textView.setText("Login Failed");
        }
    });

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            //Log.d(TAG, firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().toString());
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class));
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }

        }
    };
}

private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken accessToken){
    AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken.getToken());
    Log.d(TAG, "Entered handleFacebookAccessToken, credential:" + credential);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Entered onComplete");
            if (!task.isSuccessful()){
                Toast.makeText(Login.this,"Authentication failed.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    //if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    //}
}

}
```

Comment: same problem here... I can login using facebook, however the addOnCompleteListener method is never called.